# Brain.js is not utilizing GPU for training

Tags: node.js, neural-network, gpu, cpu, brain.js

I have been using Brain.js to train a Neural network, and it has been working just fine, except it seems that it is only using CPU to train the neural net.

I am using Windows, and the Task Manager shows the Node process using ~25% CPU (I assume it is maxing out a single thread). Looking at MSI Afterburner, the GPU is not being utilized at all.

The GPU is an Nvidia RTX 2060 super.

What can I do to make Brain.js use my GPU? I have searched around but have not been able to find much info at all so far...

Comment: Perhaps the question is irrelevant for you, but for the rest of us, the GPU works better in the browser